# Compiled libsqlite3.so doesn't work on CentOS 5.9 x86

Tags: sqlite, centos, centos5

I've compilled sqlite from sources (version 3.7.16.1) under CentOS 5.9 32bit.
It compilled successfully but i'm unable to link against it or use it anyhow.

I'm compilling like this:

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY -lstdc++" ./configure --enable-shared --enable-static=no
```

And when i try to link against it, i'm getting:

```
[sysadm@depon-460sf2 ~]$ gcc main.c -l /home/sysadm/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/sysadm/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

I call gcc under the same system sqlite was built under. ldd seems fine:

```
[sysadm@depon-460sf2 ~]$ ldd /home/sysadm/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00f2f000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x002d4000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00110000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x002ac000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00115000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x004d2000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x008d9000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0055e000)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how [the `-l` option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) works.

You must specify the library name, which is not the file path, and specify its directory as library search path:

```
gcc ... -L/home/sysadm/ -lsqlite3
```